# How can I access a grid of DIV I have created in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck since long for I am unable to access the grid of DIVs via rows and columns. I thought I could access them like gridContainer[row][col] and set some property to it. Error in console says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at HomeScript.js:25". Attaching the code snippet below for your reference. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

```js
    function genDivs (rows, cols) {
  var e = document.getElementById("gridContainer");
  for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    var row = document.createElement("div");
    row.className = "row";
    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("div");
      if (r == 10 && c == 20)
        cell.className = "gridsquare begin";
      else if (r == 10 && c == 40)
        cell.className = "gridsquare end";
      else
        cell.className = "gridsquare";
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    e.appendChild(row);
  }
}


var gridContainer = document.getElementById("gridContainer");
// gridContainer[0][0].style.backgroundColor = "pink"; (want something like this)
var gridCols = 60;
var gridRows = Math.floor(screen.height / 25) - 2;
gridContainer.style.left = ((screen.width - 25 * gridCols) / screen.width) * 50 + "%";

console.log(((screen.width - 25 * gridCols) / screen.width) * 50);
genDivs(20, 20);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #gridContainer {
      outline: 1px solid rgb(175, 216, 248);
      font-size: 0;
      position: absolute;
    }

    .row {}

    .gridsquare {
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(175, 216, 248) inset, 1px 0px 0px rgb(175, 216, 248) inset;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .begin {
      background-color: purple;
    }

    .end {
      background-color: magenta;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="gridContainer"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="HomeScript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use JS querySelector,
if you want to access 3 div in the first row use the below syntax

```
let square = document.querySelector(".row:nth-child(1) .gridsquare:nth-child(3)");
square.style.background = '#000';
```

Comment: Is there any work around so that I can have those grid in form of matrix, say: grid[1][2]

Comment: @Abhishek

yes, you can build your own function and put the above code inside that function and replace the nth-child values with arguments you pass to that function. i.e) sqaure(1,2)
function will be like this

function square(row, cell){
 let square = document.querySelector(".row:nth-child("+row+") .gridsquare:nth-child("+cell+")");
 return sqaure;
}

Comment: I think I must be missing something, copy-pasting the above code gives error "Cannot read property 'style' of null". What am I missing?

Comment: which means the dom node not selected properly @Abhishek

Comment: Hey @Karthick, now I wanted another way around. Say I have an element of grid how can I know it's row and column?

Comment: @Abhishek you can create each square with custom attribute, i.e) <div data-row='1' data-column='3'></div>, now u can easily access that sqaure by document.querySelector("div[data-row='1'][data-column='3']").style.background = '#555'

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access grid container as a JS object which it isn't, you can do something like this

```
const getRow = grid => index => {
  if (grid) {
    return grid.querySelector(`div.row:nth-child(${index + 1})`);
  }
  // handle your exception here
};

const getColumn = grid => (rowIndex, cellIndex) => {
  const row = getRow(grid)(rowIndex);
  if (row) {
    return row.querySelector(`div:nth-child(${cellIndex + 1})`);
  }
// Handle your exception here.
};

getColumn(gridContainer)(0, 0).style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
```

Comment: I am facing the below error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null"

Comment: It's because when you are accessing the grid it's not available in actual DOM, make sure that you access this functions after initializing your grid. Adding the validation in above functions will be a plus, I've updated the answer so you can understand it better